# Ruby: list instance variables of an object not inherited from its bases

Tags: ruby

Using `instance_variables` method returns a list of all instance variables in an object including those it inherits from its inheritance chain.

Is there a way to get instances defined only in its class but not from bases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, instance variables are not declared. They come to life only when accessed the first time. So, two objects of the same class can, in any given moment, have entirely different sets of instance variables.

Class inheritance is completely irrelevant when it comes to instance variables, as they are not tied to the class definition. The only thing remotely related could be finding out during which method's execution an instance variable has been created, and which class this method belongs to, but that's not possible to achieve AFAIK, and I don't see any benefit of doing so.

Comment: They are called "instance variables" for a reason, after all. +1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any clear solution (maybe it need more time to research), but i want to suggest next code:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a, :c
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
    @c = 1
  end
end

class B < A
  attr_accessor :b, :d
  def initialize(b, a)
    @b = b
    @d = 1
    super(a)
  end
end

def test
  t = B.new(1, 2)
  getters = t.instance_variables.map{ |i| i.to_s.gsub('@', '') }
  parents = B.ancestors.drop(1)

  parents.each do |i|
    curr = i.instance_methods.map(&:to_s)
    getters.each do |gt|
      if curr.include?(gt)
        getters.delete(gt)
      end
    end
  end

  getters
end

test() # => ['b', 'd']
```

**Update**: I found interesting note in 'Well Grounded Rubyist':

> Classes are important in Ruby; they’re a way to bundle and label
>   behaviors (you can have a Person class, a Task class, and so on) and
>   to create multiple objects with similar behaviors easily. But—and in
>   this respect, Ruby differs from some other object-oriented
>   languages—the real action is with the individual objects: every object
>   has the potential to “learn” behaviors (methods) that its class didn’t
>   teach it.

Mladen Jablanović gives answer to your question.